# How to get a Bitmap from VectorDrawable

Tags: android, bitmap, ontouchlistener, getpixel, android-vectordrawable

[image: Pie]

I'm still trying to solve the problem I've had since a couple of days ago and I still have not found a solution. However, I am getting there step by step. Now I have run into another roadblock.

I am trying to get `Bitmap.getpixel(int x, int y)` to return the `Color` of what the user has touched using `OnTouchListener`. The pie is a `VectorDrawable` resource, `vectordrawable.xml` I don't need to do anything with the pixel data yet, I just need to test it. So I made a `TextView` that will spit out the `Color` touched.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(imageViewOnTouchListener);
    }

    View.OnTouchListener imageViewOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            Drawable drawable = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable();
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(imageView.getResources(),R.drawable.vectordrawable);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();

            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

            textView.setText("touched color: " + "#" + Integer.toHexString(pixel));

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

But my app encounters a fatal error as soon as I touch the `ImageView`,  gives the "Unfortunately,..." message and quits. In the stack trace, I found this.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
    at com.skwear.colorthesaurus.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:38)
```

and line 38 is this one,

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
```

I kind of followed [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/10/get-touched-pixel-color-of-scaled.html). What am I doing wrong? Is it because it's a `VectorDrawable`. What can I do to get the `Color`? You can see that I have also tried `BitmapFactory` to cast the `Drawable`. Could it also be a problem with the API level of `VectorDrawable` since it was added like API 21?

Comment: Someone's point of view: https://gist.github.com/Gnzlt/6ddc846ef68c587d559f1e1fcd0900d3

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, you cannot cast `VectorDrawable` to `BitmapDrawable`. They don't have a parent-child relationship. They both are direct subclasses of `Drawable` class.

Now, to get a bitmap from drawable, you will need to create a `Bitmap` from the drawable metadata.

Probably something like this in a separate method,

```
try {
    Bitmap bitmap;

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    // Handle the error
    return null;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helped, but what about `drawable` variable? It's inputed, assigned with other methods, but not outputed, only `bitmap` have an output. I thought that it must be apply with something Android methods after it assign any methods to it, or not?

Comment: What is `BITMAP_CONFIG`?

Comment: you need to replace BITMAP_CONFIG with one of the possible Bitmap Configs available. For eg:
Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
More details can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511017/bitmap-config-hardware-vs-bitmap-config-rgb-565

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Drawable.toBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/package-summary#(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable).toBitmap(kotlin.Int,%20kotlin.Int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)) from AndroidX support library. `VectorDrawable` is child of `Drawable`.

Comment: What will happen if the aspect ratio of the VectorDrawable is different than the one of the bitmap you request?

Comment: Not sure why mine returns null!: `imvProfile.drawable.toBitmap()`