# Cannot load vector Drawable in bitmap in XML

Tags: android, bitmap, vector-graphics, layer-list

This is my first code that loads a Vector-Drawable in `layer-list`. it works fine.Later I had to change color of my vector drawable. I find that I should add bitmap to use `tint` attribute.
This is my first code and vector drawable show fine in `layer-list`.

```
<item>
    <shape
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:shape="oval">
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/accent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_black_24px"/> // this is vector drawable
```

so I changed my code to this. 
I can not load vector-Drawable in bitmap in XML.

```
<item>
    <shape
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:shape="oval">
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/accent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check_black_24px"
        android:tint="@color/white"/>
</item>
```

problem is here.
I cannot load vector-drawable in bitmap,it causes to crash my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a Bitmap from VectorDrawable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513854/how-to-get-a-bitmap-from-vectordrawable)

Comment: I think we are not same cause I'm doing in XML

Comment: are you using `android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat`?

Comment: @pskink in where?

Comment: what "in where"? are you using support vector drawable?

Comment: @pskink after  23.4.0 there is no need to put         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary=true
 in gradle. I use vectors without this annotation

Comment: i did not ask about `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary`, i asked if you are using vector drawables from support library (`VectorDrawableCompat`)

Comment: @pskink as you see in my code, No. how I can use it?