# Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE vs Bitmap.Config.RGB_565

Tags: java, android, image, performance, bitmap

API 26 [adds new option](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#HARDWARE) `Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE`:

> Special configuration, when bitmap is stored only in graphic memory.
>   Bitmaps in this configuration are always immutable. It is optimal for
>   cases, when the only operation with the bitmap is to draw it on a
>   screen.

Questions that aren't explained in docs:

1. Should we ALWAYS prefer now `Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE` over
   `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` when speed is of top priority and quality
   and mutability are not (e.g. for thumbnails, etc)?
2. Does pixel data after decoding using this option actually NOT
   consume ANY heap memory and resides in GPU memory only? If so, this seems
   to finally be a relief for `OutOfMemoryException` concern when
   working with images.
3. What quality compared to RGB_565, RGBA_F16 or ARGB_8888 should we expect
   from this option?
4. Is speed of *decoding* itself the same/better/worth compared to
   decoding with RGB_565?
5. (Thanks @CommonsWare for pointing to it in comments) What would
   happen if we exceed GPU memory when decoding an image using this
   option? Would some exception be thrown (maybe the same `OutOfMemoryException` :)?

Comment: Note that the GPU doesn't have infinite memory, so loading too many images should still cause a problem somewhere. But I agree that this option is criminally under-documented.

Comment: Has anyone been able to find the source code for this? Browsing through the [public android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-o-preview-4/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#422) didn't reveal any details regarding this feature

Comment: @Distjubo, afaik sources of Android O aren't yet public. [@romainguy](https://twitter.com/romainguy) would certainly help out with this question.

Comment: See also [this tweetstream](https://twitter.com/ZelenetS/status/901616141608427525).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Documentation and public source code is not pushed yet to [Google's git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/o-preview/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java). So my research is based only on partial information, some experiments, and on my own experience porting JVM's to various devices.

My test created large mutable Bitmap and copied it into a new HARDWARE Bitmap on a click of a button, adding it into a bitmap list. I managed to create several instances of the large bitmaps before it crashed.

I was able to find this in the [android-o-preview-4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/android-o-preview-4%5E2..android-o-preview-4/) git push:

```
+struct AHardwareBuffer;
+#ifdef EGL_EGLEXT_PROTOTYPES
+EGLAPI EGLClientBuffer eglGetNativeClientBufferANDROID (const struct AHardwareBuffer *buffer);
+#else
+typedef EGLClientBuffer (EGLAPIENTRYP PFNEGLGETNATIVECLIENTBUFFERANDROID) (const struct AHardwareBuffer *buffer);
```

And looking for the [documentation of AHardwareBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/ANDROID/EGL_ANDROID_create_native_client_buffer.txt), under the hood it is creating an `EGLClientBuffer` backed by [`ANativeWindowBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/ANDROID/EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer.txt) (native graphic buffer) in Android shared memory ("ashmem"). But the actual implementation may vary across hardware.

So as to the questions:

> 1. Should we ALWAYS prefer now Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE over Bitmap.Config.RGB_565...?

For SDK >= 26, `HARDWARE` configuration can improve the low level bitmap drawing by preventing the need to copy the pixel data to the GPU every time the same bitmap returns to the screen. I guess it can prevent losing some frames when a bitmap is added to the screen.

The memory is not counted against your app, and my test confirmed this.

The native library docs say it will return `null` if memory allocation was unsuccessful.
Without the source code, it is not clear what the Java implementation (the API implementors) will do in this case - it might decide to throw `OutOfMemoryException` or fallback to a different type of allocation.

**Update:** Experiment reveals that no OutOfMemoryException is thrown. While the allocation is successful - everything works fine. Upon failed allocation - the emulator crashed (just gone). On other occasions I've got  a weird `NullPointerException` when allocating Bitmap in app memory.

Due to the unpredictable stability, **I would not recommend using this new API in production currently**. At least not without extensive testing.

> 2. Does pixel data after decoding using this option actually NOT consume ANY heap memory and resides in GPU memory only? If so, this
>      seems to finally be a relief for `OutOfMemoryException` concern when
>      working with images.

Pixel data will be in shared memory (probably texture memory), but there still be a small `Bitmap` object in Java referencing it (so "ANY" is inaccurate).

Every vendor can decide to implement the actual allocation differently, it's not a public API they are bound to.
So `OutOfMemoryException` may still be an issue. I'm not sure how it can be handled correctly.

> 3. What quality compared to RGB_565/ARGB_8888?

The `HARDWARE` flag is not about quality, but about pixel storage location. Since the configuration flags cannot be `OR`-ed, I suppose that the default (`ARGB_8888`) is used for the decoding.

(Actually, the `HARDWARE` enum seem like a hack to me).

> 4. Is speed of decoding itself the same/better/worse...?

`HARDWARE` flag seem unrelated to decoding, so the same as `ARGB_8888`.

> 5. What would happen if we exceed GPU memory?

My test result in very bad things when memory is running out.
The emulator crashed horribly sometimes, and I've got unexpected unrelated NPE on other occasions. No OutOfMemoryException occurred, and there was also no way to tell when the GPU memory is running out, so no way to foresee this.

Comment: Is there any way to protect against memory issues when using this decoding?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I didn't find a way to do that

Comment: So... no reason to use it then? Do you even have a way to get the amount of memory on the GPU (free vs total)  ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper My research 8 months ago didn't find a way to get the amount of GPU memory, this is what I wrote in my answer. I didn't check if there was an update since.

Comment: Nice work. Incredible how poorly documented this is in the official docs.