# How to get bitmap from URL using Coil?

Tags: android, kotlin, palette, image-load, coil

I want to load a bitmap from URL and then use palette API to get some colors from that.

On the documentation page, I cannot find the code for getting bitmap directly!

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `target` method and cast the drawable to `bitmap` as

```
    val loader = ImageLoader(this)
    val req = ImageRequest.Builder(this)
        .data("https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/saluki/n02091831_3400.jpg") // demo link
        .target { result ->
            val bitmap = (result as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
        }
        .build()

    val disposable = loader.enqueue(req)
```

If you using coroutines then use `GetRequest` (with overloaded `execute` method with `suspend`) in your CoroutineScope as:

```
  coroutineScope.launch{
    val loader = ImageLoader(this)
    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this)
        .data("https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/saluki/n02091831_3400.jpg")
        .allowHardware(false) // Disable hardware bitmaps.
        .build()

    val result = (loader.execute(request) as SuccessResult).drawable
    val bitmap = (result as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
}
```

Comment: What does this line do `val disposable = loader.execute(req)`

Comment: @IdrisStack that executes the build request and returns a [request disposable](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/api/coil-base/coil.request/-request-disposable/) that can be used to dispose of queued requests, free up resources, or can invoke `await` for immediate execution.

Comment: Why do you disable hardware?

Comment: @AchrafAmil I guess it's was probably because of some [stability or compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45660636/4936904) at that time.

Comment: @AchrafAmil because many other native libraries do not support it e.g. Pallette, Firebase ML Kit, ... and you cannot pass it to them it will throw an error

Comment: You should avoid creation of `ImageLoader` every time image load is required because of this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231499040#comment3

Comment: if image was previously loaded and available in cache (memory/disk) then it will return it instantly? basically I have the list of times with image and user can click share button on each item to share text and image content of specific item

Comment: @user924 Coil uses [in-memory cache](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/17) so you can try running a test to load large images and see if it always download the images or how efficient it is to use cache.

Answer (score 0):

according to [Coil's own document](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/migrating/#background-thread), you can download a bitmap in the background in the following way:

```
val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
.data(url)
.build()
val drawable = context.imageLoader.execute(request).drawable
```