# Adding background image using Watch Face library (Wear OS)

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api, watchface

Last month Google / Jetpack released the stable version of the [Watch Face library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/wear-watchface) ([blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/12/develop-watch-faces-with-stable-jetpack.html)). It is stated that:

> The `androidx.wear.watchface` package is the new recommended library for developing WearOS watch faces.

On GitHub there is a [demo watch face project](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/WatchFaceAlphaKotlin), made with the library, which includes many features. However, it does not explain how to add a background.

How should I add a background image to a `androidx.wear.watchface`-based watch face?

Answer (score 0):

The change to the is probably just to replace the background color.

https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/19726c10ac0c881c9d748400294fdb6bb9585ab7/WatchFaceAlphaKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/alpha/AnalogWatchCanvasRenderer.kt#L221

```
    val bitmap: Bitmap = TODO()
    override fun render(canvas: Canvas, bounds: Rect, zonedDateTime: ZonedDateTime) {
//        val backgroundColor = if (renderParameters.drawMode == DrawMode.AMBIENT) {
//            watchFaceColors.ambientBackgroundColor
//        } else {
//            watchFaceColors.activeBackgroundColor
//        }
//
//        canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor)

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, bounds, null)
```

How are you sourcing the Bitmap? If you are downloading over the network you can use something like the following with appropriate disk caching.

[How to get bitmap from URL using Coil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61892301/how-to-get-bitmap-from-url-using-coil)